# Python 3, beautiful soup, get next tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the following html part which repeates itself several times with other href links:

```
<div class="product-list-item  margin-bottom">
<a title="titleexample" href="http://www.urlexample.com/example_1" data-style-id="sp_2866">
```

Now I want to get all the href links in this document that are directly after the div tag with the class "product-list-item".
Pretty new to beautifulsoup and nothing that I came up with worked.

Thanks for your ideas.

EDIT: Does not really have to be beautifulsoup; when it can be done with regex and the python html parser this is also ok.

EDIT2: What I tried (I'm pretty new to python, so what I did might be totaly stupid from an advanced viewpoint):

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(htmlsource)
x = soup.find_all("div")
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i].get("class") and "product-list-item" in x[i].get("class"):
        print(x[i].get("class"))
```

This will give me a list of all the "product-list-item" but then I tried something like

```
print(x[i].get("class").next_element)
```

Because I thought next_element or next_sibling should give me the next tag but it just leads to AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'next_element'. So I tried with only the first list element:

```
print(x[i][0].get("class").next_element)
```

Which led to this error: return self.attrs[key] KeyError: 0.
Also tried with .find_all("href") and .get("href") but this all leads to the same errors.

EDIT3: Ok seems I found out how to solve it, now I did:

```
x = soup.find_all("div")

for i in range(len(x)):    
    if x[i].get("class") and "product-list-item" in x[i].get("class"):
        print(x[i].next_element.next_element.get("href"))
```

This can also be shortened by using another attribute to the find_all function:

```
x = soup.find_all("div", "product-list-item")
for i in x:
    print(i.next_element.next_element.get("href"))
```

greetings

Comment: can you show us what you have tried? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get all the href links in this document that are directly after the div tag with the class "product-list-item"

To find the first `<a href>` element in the `<div>`:

```
links = []
for div in soup.find_all('div', 'product-list-item'): 
    a = div.find('a', href=True) # find <a> anywhere in <div>
    if a is not None:
       links.append(a['href'])
```

It assumes that the link is inside `<div>`. Any elements in `<div>` before the first `<a href>` are ignored.

If you'd like; you can be more strict about it e.g., taking the link only if it is the first child in `<div>`:

```
a = div.contents[0] # take the very first child even if it is not a Tag
if a.name == 'a' and a.has_attr('href'):
   links.append(a['href'])
```

Or if `<a>` is not inside `<div>`:

```
a = div.find_next('a', href=True) # find <a> that appears after <div>
if a is not None:
   links.append(a['href'])
```

[There are many ways to search and navigate in BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

If you search with [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html), you could also use xpath and css expressions if you are familiar with them.